# How to dynamic add new input with AngularJS model use JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.name = "Ann";
$scope.test = "Hello, {{name}}!";

var element = document.createElement("input");
element.setAttribute('ng-model', "name");
document.getElementById("preview").appendChild(element);
```

And HTML-code:

```
<div id="preview">
    <p ng-bind-html="test"></p>
</div>
{{name}}
```

But at page I see `Hello, {{name}}!`, empty input and `Ann` name. How to setting input and div for show name? That I change name in input and name changed in div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NYEBRhlEtYyqagOixfyB?p=preview)

```
 $scope.name = "Ann";
$scope.test = "Hello, {{name}}!";

var element = document.createElement("input");
element.setAttribute('ng-model', "name");
document.getElementById("preview").appendChild(element);

$compile(document.getElementById("preview"))($scope);
```

Comment: It isn't a true solution for me, because the `$scope.test` is dynamic string. And I don't know, how many `{{name}}` I have

Comment: It will be updated when your $scope.name will update. Your Hello 'name' is sync to your input box. So whatever there in $scope.name will be shown. :)

Answer (score 1):

ng-html compile does not compile bindings but only parses the static html. If you want to also have your syntax compiled in strings you need to implement custom directive for that:

```
app.directive('ngHtmlCompile', ["$compile", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngHtmlCompile, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                element.html(newValue);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

and then you can compile:

```
<div ng-html-compile="Hello, {{name}}!"></div>
```